# Closed path trough only finitely many times an open subset disjoint of his base point?

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups

My problem:

Let $\alpha$ be a closed path of $[0,1]$ in the union of three no disjoint open balls $B_1,B_2,B_3\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3=\emptyset$, if the base point of $\alpha$ is $x_0\in B_1\cap B_2$, then $\alpha$ through only finitely many times the intersection $B_2\cap B_3$?

Note that through finitely many times $B_2\cap B_3$ means that $\alpha^{-1}(B_2\cap B_3)$ is finite union of disjoint open subintervals of [0,1].

I need this result to prove that the fundamental group of this three balls are finitely generate by lines connecting fixed points in his intersections.

Comment: Please give a precise definition of "$\alpha$ goes only finitely many times through the intersection".

Comment: It means that $\alpha^{-1}(B_2\cap B_3)$ is finite union of open disjoint intervals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Then you should edit your question, readers do not want to look at comments to get all information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $\alpha$ can go only infinitely many times through the intersection $B_2 \cap B_3$. Take a path from $x_0$ to a boundary point $x_1 \in \text{bd} B_3 \cap B_2$. Then you can run in finite time through infinitely loops $l_n$ in $\overline B_3 \cap B_2$ of length $2^{-n}$ such that $l_n \cap \text{bd} B_3 = \{x_1\}$. Finally take any path from $x_1$ to $x_0$. Drawing a picture is helpful.